# Git: check whether file exists in some version

Tags: git, version-control

In my application, I'm using git for version management of some external files

I'm using commands like `git show HEAD~1:some_file` to get a certain version (based on git tag, commit hash or relation to HEAD) of a file.
When the file does not exist, a 'fatal' message is outputted (I think to the stderr pipe).
e.g.

> fatal: Path 'some_file' does not exist in 'HEAD~1'

Is there a clean command to check whether a file exists in a certain version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best thing I've found so far is:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD~1 --name-only
```

Which outputs the list of file names in a specific version. 
I'll need to parse the output and filter a specific file. Therefore its a bit less direct than I hoped, but a piece of cake.

Comment: You could avoid parsing by including the filepath in the ls-tree command (skipping -r as well): `git ls-tree HEAD~1 --name-only path/to/file`.  ls-tree doesn't support cat-file's -e option to give a yes/no exit status, though, so it requires another step to use in a conditional in a script.  (-z or -n, pipe to "grep ." to get status, etc)

Answer (score 22):

How are you using this? In a script? You can always check the exit code. And `git cat-file` may be better suited:

```
git cat-file -e HEAD~1:some_file
```

With the `-e` option, it will exit with non-zero error code when object doesn't exist and with 0 when it does. It will, however, print the `fatal: Not a valid object name` as well, but that can be easily suppressed:

```
    git cat-file -e HEAD~1:some_file 2> /dev/null && echo Not found. || echo Found.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm indeed calling this from a (ruby) script. `cat-file` does nothing different from the `git show` asaik. `-e` suppresses the stdout, but not stderr. Therefore, still getting fatals. Instead of suppressing it, I hoped there'd be a command to ask git: 'does this file exist?'

Comment: The order is not good and should be:
`git cat-file -e HEAD~1:some_file 2> /dev/null && echo Found. || echo Not Found`

Answer (score 7):

Since all you need is the exit code from the command, you can redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null:

```
git show HEAD~1:some_file > /dev/null 2>&1
```

An exit code of 0 means the file exists.

You should be able to use that whole line within your Ruby system call:

```
exit_code = system("git show HEAD~1:some_file > /dev/null 2>&1")
```

For the benefit of anyone doing this in Bash, you can get the exit code this way:

```
git show HEAD~1:some_file > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  # the file does not exist
fi
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thanks. The accepted answer produces too much output, and I was sure there is a way to limit it to just one file with consequent return code analyzing.