# Testing for presence of a file in a git repo

Tags: git, github

I am working on code to compare the head version of files across multiple branches in git/GitHub and deployed on execution servers.

```
dev branch
test branch
main branch

\\devsrv\prod\src\thefile.py
\\testsrv\prod\src\thefile.py
\\prodsrv\prod\src\thefile.py
```

Using `git diff`, this compares the head version of `thefile.py` on the dev and test branches.

```
git diff --exit-code origin/dev..origin/test -- C:\src\therepo\src\thefile.py
git diff --exit-code origin/dev..origin/main -- C:\src\therepo\src\thefile.py
```

However, `git diff` does not appear to indicate if the file does not yet exist in the test or main branch.

The dev branch is my current branch. How can I test for the file existence of thefile.py in the test and main branches? Must I `git switch` and `git pull` to each branch?

Comment: BTW, have you considered using worktrees?

Comment: [Git’s documentation says that `git switch` is experimental](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) - instead, use `git checkout` or worktrees  (are you thinking of `svn switch`?).

Comment: @Dai, I just started reading about worktrees today.

Comment: As for your original question, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461761/git-check-whether-file-exists-in-some-version - you’ll need to check for file existence _first_ with `git ls-file` which does not require a `checkout` - or use `git show` and check the exitcode.

Comment: @Dai a note: the documentation still states that `git switch` and `git restore` are experimental, but they are actually here to stay. They were [introduced in 2.23](https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/) (2019) and they're definitely here to stay.

Comment: @LeGEC I'm not disputing that, I'm just saying that `git switch` is essentially still in beta so it _might_ break (I'm not a `git` internals expert, but can anyone say if a misbehaving `git switch` could cause repo corruption... or not?)

Comment: `git switch` is a reskin of `git checkout`, it literally invokes checkout after parsing different options. `ret = checkout_main(argc, argv, prefix, &opts,options, switch_branch_usage, &new_branch_info);`

Comment: I can appreciate the discussion of `git switch`, but this question is about `git diff`. It would be helpful if you would delete comments that only reference `git switch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to require that the files exist in both tips, reference them directly.

```
git diff --exit-code origin/dev:src/file.py origin/test:src/file.py
```

That'll get you return code 1 if they both exist but differ, 128 if either or both doesn't exist, 0 if they both exist and are identical.

---

To bail if a specific object doesn't exist you can use `git rev-parse`, the way I'm showing here looks weird but will vet all the specs before bailing if any are bad:

```
git rev-parse origin/dev:src/file.py >/dev/null;  ((rc+=$?))
git rev-parse origin/test:src/file.py >/dev/null; ((rc+=$?))
git rev-parse origin/main:src/file.py >/dev/null; ((rc+=$?))
(( rc!=0 )) && exit 1
```

Comment: This is helpful. But I would like to be able to report which file does not exist. Would `git diff --exit-code origin/dev:src/file.py origin/dev:src/file.py` work?

Comment: This appears to work. But, `git diff --exit-code origin/dev..origin/dev -- C:\src\therepo\src/filexxx.py` does not identify that the file does not exist. Need to run `git diff` three (3) times; test existence on dev, test existence on test, and compare between dev and test.

Comment: Many thanks, @jthill. I think that `git rev-parse` will do it.